# Is there a way to execute on applescript when a server becomes available?

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

I am trying to execute a script when a server becomes available (a bit like when the OS detect the presence of a time capsule device and it starts the backup.)  I didn't find a simple way to attach an applescript to an system event. Is there a way?

I am not looking for anything that requires a compiler. I am simply looking at attaching to an OS event (a bit like "Folder Actions" I guess, but for a server.)

Comment: [Cross-posted to SU.](http://superuser.com/questions/299970/is-there-a-way-to-execute-on-applescript-when-a-server-becomes-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is run an script with an `idle` handler that periodically checks to see if the server is available and if so executes another script or another portion of the same script.

Comment: since i didn't get any better answer, this is a work around I will accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html) for that purpose. Here is an example of a launchd config plist that will execute an AppleScript when a disk is mounted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>Example</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
            <string>/Users/sakra/Documents/Test.applescript</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartOnMount</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

To activate the config plist save it to the LaunchAgents folder in your Library folder as `Example.plist`.

From the Terminal you can then use the command `launchctl` to activate `Example.plist` by running:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/Example.plist
```

The AppleScript will then be run each time a filesystem is mounted.

To deactivate it, run:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/Example.plist
```

Comment: I guess this answers my question partially. The StartOnMount option specifies the script to run when a disk is mounted. What I really want is my script to launch when a server is available on the network. I will look into launchd's man pages see if there is anything I can use.